# In Python, how do I forward users to an external server with parameters?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect

I've written Python code (on Google App Engine) that forward users from my server, allows users to log in and provide access to their Twitter account through OAUTH, then get redirected back to my server (http://www.website.com). My code for that works fine.

All my Python code is running in the first server (http:/www.website.com). However, I then want redirect a user to a third server (http://www.example.com) with parameters. I tried the following:

```
import flask

var1 = 'abcdef12345' #For simplicity, these are hard coded 
var2 = 'def4321' #However, in the real script they're dynamically created
var3 = 'qwerty98765'

THIRD_SERVER_URL = "http://www.example.com/entrance" 
return flask.redirect(url_try(THIRD_SERVER_URL, _external=True, x1=var1, x2=var2, x3=var3))
```

I was hoping that the code would redirect the user to `"http://www.example.com/entrance?x1=abcdef12345&x2=def4321&x3=qwerty98765"`. However, I'm instead getting a 500 Internal Server Error

I've also tried:

```
import webapp2  

return self.redirect(THIRD_SERVER_URL + "?x1=" + var1 + "&x2=" + var2 + "&x3=" + var3)
```

However, that failed too with the same Error 500.

Does anybody know what might be the best option in Python for forwarding (redirecting?) users to an external URL with parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the stack trace error log say about the 500?

Flask's redirect accepts just the url and response code (302, etc).  (Where is `url_try` defined?)  You should be able to do this:

```
from flask import redirect
...
...
return redirect(THIRD_SERVER_URL + "?x1=" + var1 + "&x2=" + var2 + "&x3=" + var3, 302)
```

Comment: Wonderful :) This worked! I couldn't get Google App Engine to do 'from flask import redirect'. Instead, I just had 'import flask' and used "return flask.direct etc etc". Thank you for pointing the way!

Comment: Re: the approach, is this a massively insecure method of transferring the data? The Var1 and Var2 refer to Twitter tokens.